# Samba user and guest permissions

Tags: server, permissions, samba, 14.04

I have a folder in `/var/www/html/` that people upload files to via PHP called `store`.

`store` has the permissions `rwxrwxr--` it is owned by the user `josh` and the `www-data` group.

The `store` folder is also an SMB share and works if I use `josh` to login to it. However I need everyone to be able to access it but without write permissions as well.

This is what I have tried in my samba config:

```
[propellor]
path = /var/www/html/store
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = yes
write list = josh
create mask = 755
```

Mapping a network drive in Windows allows me to read and write if I use `josh` credentials but will not let me open the share at all if I am a guest or use another (Windows) user account.

I am missing something in my settings or permissions surly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new user first: `sudo useradd samba-guest`.

Search your `smb.conf` for `guest account`. Set this to `samba-guest` (`guest account = samba-guest`).

Now restart Samba and it should work.

For more info, please click [here](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html).

**Note:** don't forget to give `samba-guest` read permissions for `/var/www/html/store`.

Comment: How would I apply user specific permissions to a directory without overwriting the owner, group and existing permissions. Thanks.

Comment: The easiest way is to give all users read permissions using `chmod -R a+r /var/www/html/store/`. Otherwise you could set the `guest account` to your own account and put `read only = yes` in your shares. Please note that I'm not a security expert but I think that'll do it.

Comment: I think the samba-guest = josh with readonly did the trick. The chmod -R a+r didn't work for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sticky for the other file permission in samba share file. or you can also add the guest user and change the permission for them on share folder.